# Windows phone 7 ListBox animation on selection

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a `ListBox` in my application that contains `TextBlock`s displaying some data. The `TextBlock`s are setup to fire an event when the user clicks on them.

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxCategories"
         Margin="0,0,-12,0"
         ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxItems}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17"
                  Width="432">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"
                   Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This works as I want it to, but it'd be great if I could provide some sort of animation when the user clicks on an item. For instance, when you select a contact from the phone's address book and click on one of the actions (such as "send email" or "call mobile") the text briefly moves before the selected action is performed. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a story board with blend to move the text box.
2. Start the story board from the click event handler.
3. Perform your action in the story board finished event.

Comment: Thanks, your answer got me looking in the right direction. The Silverlight toolkit for WP7 (http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) includes `TransitioningContentControl` that simplifies storyboards.